# can i use Mesa 18.1.1 as intel graphic driver and nvidia 415.25 graphic driver for nvidia 940mx and switch them using sudo prime-select?

Tags: intel-graphics, 18.10, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-prime, mesa

My laptop has hybrid graphics with ubuntu 18.10 and both Intel HD620 and Nvidia 940mx. when I switch Nvidia graphics it works with zero lag, but Intel graphic lags, so I installed mesa 18.1.1 for Intel. I have a doubt whether ubuntu ay conflict both drivers. because I got Disabling IRQ #16 error once. so I would like to know is it okay to install both drivers and also will intel use Mesa and Nvidia use 415.25 only? and when I use sudo prime-select will drivers switch correctly?

I will attach to the tutorial which I end up with this scenario.
https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/How-to:-DXVK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did full research on this, I think I can answer my question by my self. So there are little conflicts between Mesa and Nvidia graphics drivers. If you installed both of them in the boot time you will see something like "Disabling IRQ 16" which reflects there are some conflictions among drivers. The confliction because Mesa has its own Vulkan drivers and also Nvidia too. So ubuntu confuses which Vulkan driver to be used at the boot time.

So the best approach is to use Nvidia Vulkan drivers and avoid installing Mesa Vulkan drivers, So you will be fine